# How to Get Distinct Value of DataTable and Append New Column with the Count of each distinct value returned [UIPath][VB.Net]?

Tags: datatable, uipath, uipath-studio

I am a newbie in UIPath.
I have a DataTable with these headers:

1.) Date

2.) Error

I want to extract a Distinct Date for every error, and use this code:

```
dtQuery = ExtractDataTable.DefaultView.ToTable(True,{"Date","Error"})
```

With this, I get my desired result. My problem is how can I append (a new Column, "Count") EACH COUNT of DISTINCT VALUES given? For Example:

```
DATE       |  ERROR               |  COUNT

2/27/2019  |  Admin Query String  |  

2/27/2019  |  404 Shield          |  

2/26/2019  |  404 Shield          |  

2/25/2019  |  404 Shield          |  

2/25/2019  |  Admin Query String  |
```

I tried to use ADD DATA COLUMN ACTIVITY with these properties:

```
Column Name = "COUNT"
Data Table = dtQuery
DefaultValue = ExtractDataTable.DefaultView.ToTable(True,{"Date","Error"}).Rows.Count
```

But by using this, it gives me this:

```
DATE       |  ERROR               |  COUNT

2/27/2019  |  Admin Query String  |  5

2/27/2019  |  404 Shield          |  5

2/26/2019  |  404 Shield          |  5

2/25/2019  |  404 Shield          |  5

2/25/2019  |  Admin Query String  |  5
```

Thanks in advance! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of research, here is what I learned.

I can iterate on each item of the datatable by using FOR EACH ROW Activity.

So for every row item of my dtQuery, I add ASSIGN Activity that looks like this:

```
row(2) = [item i want to add]
```

But that doesn't answer my question. I want to know the count of each unique item with 2 criteria - They are same DATE and ERROR.

Maybe I can code directly on the Excel File?

So I researched for Excel Formula that looks like "Select Distinct Col1....etc."

I found this video tutorial, hope it might help: [Countif](https://support.office.com/client/en-us/videoplayer/embed/RWeTTK?pid=ocpVideo0-innerdiv-oneplayer&jsapi=true&postJsllMsg=true&maskLevel=20&market=en-us)

But its only for a single criterion, so I found this: [Countifs](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-if-two-criteria-match)

So to wrap it up,
[For Each Row Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HinJl.png)

1.) I loop inside dtQuery using For Each Row Activity

2.) Inside loop, I add Assign Activity with this code

`row(2) = "=COUNTIFS('LookUp Sheet'!B:B,'Result Sheet'!A" & indexerRow + 2 & ",'LookUp Sheet'!D:D,'Result Sheet'!B" & indexerRow + 2 & ")"`

Hope this help others who will be stumbling upon the same problem. Happy Automating! ^_^

Comment: Hi One more way to Use grouping of Date via linq too. :) that will give you output like:- DT.Select.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("DATE")).[Select](function(g) g)
it will return you result as Igrouping<String,Datarow> then you can use Foreach for further process

Comment: @Aksh, thanks to that! I'll note it and use it on my next journey! ^_^

Comment: I have shared this longback in Uipath community forum too. you can look over there. if not then i can share you too :) if needed